# Execute function every n commands in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bots

I'd like to make a program which will be executed every n commands in bash. For example, I want user to answer for a question  for every 5 commands in bash.

I think this function can be implemented using only bash script, be I couldn't find a proper solution for this. I don't want to compile a new bash and  I think this can be done by a bash script. If so, do I have to change bashrc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can trap `DEBUG` signal in shell with a custom function.

```
runcmd() { if (( n==5 )); then n=0; pwd; else ((n++)); fi; }

trap 'runcmd' DEBUG
```

Change `pwd` with your custom command or script.

- `trap 'handler' DEBUG` calls `handler` after running every command in shell **but won't call `runcmd` when just enter is pressed in shell**.

**Edit:** Thanks to @kojro: you can shorten this function as:

```
runcmd() { (( n++ % 5 )) || pwd; }
```

Comment: You could still write it `runcmd() { (( n++ % 5 )) || pwd; }`. :P

Comment: If `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set, then pressing just enter in shell will still trigger this every fifth _line_, since `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a command. I'm sure some readers will find that obvious, but some may not.

Comment: (Also note that the original `runcmd` is off-by-one and executes every sixth command.)

Comment: Yes @kojiro: Few months back I encountered same issue while setting both `PROMPT_COMMAND` and `trap DEBUG`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` shell variable to run a command after every user command (every time the prompt is displayed) and use a counter in that to get something to execute every fifth time:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="if [ \"\$HELLO_COUNTER\" -le 0 ]; then HELLO_COUNTER=5; echo 'Hello, world.'; else let --CTR; fi"
```

EDIT: @kojiro has a good idea in the comments to use the builtin `LINENO` variable instead of a new counter, as in

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='(( LINENO % 5 )) || echo "Hello world."'
```

I like that.

Comment: I believe `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed even if you press empty enter without entering any command.

Comment: It might be more appropriate to use the LINENO variable than a new, arbitrary HELLO_COUNTER.

Comment: @anubhava sure, but PROMPT_COMMAND is a command… #stackoverflow

Comment: Here: `PROMPT_COMMAND='(( LINENO % 5 )) || echo "every fifth"'`